# Optimal way to write middleware for checkingadmin with and without redirecting

Tags: node.js, express

I have written an express authentication middleware. The first one which uses `app.all('*')` is used to setup a flash object which is then used to setup a locals object. The checkAdmin middleware allows the route to proceed but gives me a local variable which I can check in my ejs for displaying portions of the page that should be viewed by admin only. However, other users still have access to this page. They just cannot see everything. Therefore, in my checkAdmin() middleware, I am using return next() wheather a user is admin or not.

The middleware function:

```
app.all('*',middleware.checkAdmin)





middleware.isAdmin =function(req,res,next){
        //Check if the admin is set to true or not


        pool.query(`Select RoleID from userroles where UserID = ${req.user.id}`,function(err,rows,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            if(rows[0]){                  //This should not really happen, where the role is undefined. Every user should have a role, but checking it just in case
                if (rows[0].RoleID == 1){
                    return next()
                }
            }
            req.flash("message", "You need to have admin previledge to acccess this page")
            res.redirect('back');     //From express 4 onwards this should allow me to redirect to the same page the request came from.
        })

    }
middleware.checkAdmin=function(req,res,next){
        //Check if the admin is set to true or not

        if(req.user){
            pool.query(`Select RoleID from userroles where UserID = ${req.user.id}`,function(err,rows,fields){  
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                if(rows[0]){                  //This should not really happen, where the role is undefined. Every user should have a role, but checking it just in case
                    if (rows[0].RoleID == 1){
                        req.flash("checkAdmin","admin")
                        return next()
                    }
                }
                return next()     
            })
        }else{
            return next()
        }

    }
app.use(function(req,res,next){

    res.locals.currentUser=req.user;
    res.locals.error=req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success=req.flash("success");
    res.locals.message=req.flash("message");
    res.locals.checkAdmin=req.flash("checkAdmin");   //I am using this so that I can show the admin navbar element only if the user is signed in as admin
    next()
})
```

My isAdmin middleware is used in routes like:

```
router.get("/admin", middleware.isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    res.render("admin.ejs")
})
```

I could not find an authenticaiton setup online that solves this issue therefore I came up this this code. But I am not sure if this is an optimal way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use sessions?
Then you can set the role on login and you can write middleware like this:

```
function authMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session.isAdmin) {
        next();
    }
    else {
        //set error message here.
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Then you could add this with app or router .use like this:

```
//protected routers
app.use('/protected', authMiddleWare, (req, res) => {});
```

The library you should use for sessions is express-session.

I am not sure this answered your question, I hope it helped.